# How to stream your ipad screen via standard streaming protocol

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation, ipados, streaming

I want a solution to stream iPad screen wirelessly to anywhere I want (especially video chats).

The solution should rely only on some **standard protocols** like rtsp or some other (I’m new to streaming and not familiar to all protocols for that).

Basically I want a solution that would work like streaming via quicktime and a cable (got me a separate window with iPad screen) but without quicktime and a cable (and mac for that matter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no good (first- or third-party) app for this and it's not built into the OS.

I've had better luck using an AirPlay receiver if you absolutely can not use HDMI out (or USB-C Display Port on the newer iPads) to get video out of the iPad using native solutions.

- https://www.airsquirrels.com/airparrot/ (or perhaps their [new offering Ditto](https://www.airsquirrels.com/ditto?hsCtaTracking=303f9364-d117-4176-b7bd-0930defc6d6e%7C44a04c64-800f-46aa-a7a2-9ad2f6c481dd)) - AirParrot has been reliable for quite a many year / iOS release for wireless streaming.
- [Connect iPad to a display with a cable](https://support.apple.com/guide/ipad/connect-to-a-display-with-a-cable-ipadf1276cde/ipados) - there are many hardware solutions to split / rebroadcast a video signal so if you absolutely need control over the codec - this is the way forward for you.

Comment: Just, what is first-party app?

Answer (score 1):

There are apps you can try, but I can't speak to their stability, like Larix Screencaster https://apps.apple.com/us/app/larix-screencaster/id1477313005

> Larix Screencaster allows streaming the content of your screen via SRT/RTMP/RTSP/RIST
>
> Larix Screencaster allows streaming your device' screen content in
> real-time over WiFi, EDGE, 3G, LTE and 5G:
>
> ~ Live H.264/AAC encoding.
>
> ~ HEVC(H.265) encoding (where available).
>
> ~ RTSP and RTMP streaming.
>
> ...

Comment: I’ve tried it. I don’t see how exactly I should configure it to be able to see the stream from any device. It seems to want a server url and act as a client which isn’t what I need.

Comment: Their apps are a bit confusing. They also have broadcaster https://apps.apple.com/app/larix-broadcaster/id1042474385

Comment: Good call on their screen caster - it's the closest thing to an app match and I don't test it either as I'm super happy with [both solutions in my answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/457843/5472). +1 for the link - good source